# Not able to clone private repo from github using ssh

Tags: github, gitkraken

I have an account with github.com for some time now.  Have my ssh key added and can clone other public as well as private (once granted) repos without any problem.

Below command to confirm that github authentication is successful.

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi naidu! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
$
```

Lately me and my friend was given access to a private repository. My friend can clone the repo but I cannot.  When I try, I get below error:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:private_org_repo/xxxx-yyyy.git
Cloning into 'xxxx-yyyy'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
$
```

Searched whole internet looking for a possible glitch but I could not find any solution so far.  I am able to clone using https but this is not what I want.

Anyone can give some clues on what else to try?

Comment: Have you had a look into your `~/.ssh/config` file already? One possibility can be that a wrong key is used for Github. Happened to me once when I used to have multiple Github accounts and the wrong key was being used. 
Might also wanna check your git config and set user name and email appropriately `git config [--global] user.name "Full Name"`, `git config [--global] user.email "email@address.com"`.

Comment: If the wrong key is used then `ssh -T git@github.com` wont work.  On top, I am still able to clone other repos using ssh.  Therefore I dont think that is an issue.  What issue you had with your `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: My problem at the time was that a different keys were used when I tested the connection and when I cloned, so the test would always work but the clone would not.

Comment: I looked up `~/.ssh/config` and do have some connections info but nothing for github.com.  Therefore I assume this is not the issue.  Also because I am still able to clone some other repos.

Answer (score 0):

Was bit wired but deleting the existing keys at github.com and reading helped.  Cannot explain why it worked though.